# Why I cannot create a pure object via a function-constructor in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, prototype

I've got a question about a Javascript inheritance. I wanna create a pure object. I can do it using a `Object.create(null)`. But I decided to create it via a constructor function.

```
let User = function () {};

User.prototype = null;
```

So now I can expect, that every object created with `new User()` syntax, will have no prototype whatsoever.
But

```
let user = new User();

console.log(user.__proto__ == Object.prototype); //true
```

Why it's not null here? Why it's not pure here? I think I'm missing something important.

Comment: try this `User.__proto__ = null;`  `User.prototype` and `user.__proto__` are 2 diffrent fields

Comment: `__proto__` is added by the `new` operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Comment: @AndriNic No, don't do that, no reason to mess with the link to `Function.prototype`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I can expect, that every object created with `new User()` syntax, will have no prototype whatsoever.

Yeah, that's a reasonable expectation, but JS doesn't work like that. The `new` operator falls back to creating an object from `Object.prototype` if the constructor's `.prototype` is not an object. Only ES5 introduced a way to create pure objects inheriting from `null` with `Object.create`.

Answer (score -1):

The **proto** getter function exposes the value of the internal [[Prototype]] of an object. For objects created using an object literal, this value is Object.prototype. To compare value of the internal [[Prototype]] of object "user" :

```
       console.log(user.__proto__ == Object.prototype.__proto__); //false
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPCYB.png)